# Why the popup shadow doesn't show?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this popup with a shadow effect, and in the designer view it looks fine, but when I run the app, there's a black rectangle around the popup, I also added a margin for the borders, but it just made the rectangle bigger

```
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtName}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="AlertPopup">
        <Border Margin="0,0,15,15" Background="#272C30" BorderBrush="#6C757D" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" BlurRadius="25" Direction="315" ShadowDepth="15" Opacity="0.3"/>
            </Border.Effect>
            <TextBlock Padding="7" Foreground="#ADB5BD" Background="Transparent" FontSize="12"
            Text="The file name can't contain any of the following characters:&#x0a;\ / : * ? &quot; &gt; &lt; |"/>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
```

This is what it looks like in the designer view:
[image]

This is what it looks like when I run it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `AllowsTransparency="True"` on your `Popup`:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtName}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="AlertPopup" IsOpen="true" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Border Margin="0,0,15,15" Background="#272C30" BorderBrush="#6C757D" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" BlurRadius="25" Direction="315" ShadowDepth="15" Opacity="0.3"/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <TextBlock Padding="7" Foreground="#ADB5BD" Background="Transparent" FontSize="12"
    Text="The file name can't contain any of the following characters:&#x0a;\ / : * ? &quot; &gt; &lt; |"/>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

This is what it will look like when you run it:

[image]